# Host IdentityServer4 on IISExpress

Tags: .net-core, iis-express, identityserver4

Is there some tutorial on how to host IdentityServer4, written in .NET Core on IISExpress.

Since IS4 is written in .NET Core it can not be hosted (or maybe can, not sure) on classic IIS, so I have read somewhere that I should host it on IISExpress or it should be self-hosted. 
I guess that ISSExpress is a easier way to go and I guess I need some self-sign certificate, but I am not sure what are all steps I need to preform to make it run on my local machine so I can use it for token-based authentication.

I was looking around and searching on the internet, but I didn't found any step by step on how to host IS4 on IISExpress and create self-sign certificate.

Can someone help me with this one please?

Comment: Your question is more "how can I host an ASP.NET Core application on IIS. This is how VS creates a new core project -- it's IIS Express hosted by default.

Comment: this may help: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS